# Hiding WordPress image links in headless CMS setup

Tags: wordpress, astrojs, headless-cms

Just getting started with using WordPress as a headless CMS and have just run into a small issue.

I am pulling through post data to my front end including the featured image, however, it is very easy for someone to find the url for the WordPress site by just opening the image in a new tab.

How best should I go about this?
Am I better off working out a way to display images from a url (like a CDN) and pull that link through?

Is there a way to mask the image url getting pulled through?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up creating a field using advanced custom fields in WP and building the front end to use that field as the image URL, so able to link images from a CDN

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).